# No suitable driver found for jdbc:postgresql but I have install driver

Tags: java, postgresql, maven

I want to connect to my database so I have created this class to connect

```java
public class DBConnection {
    private final String url = "jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5433/Litopia";
    private final String user = "postgres";
    private final String password = "postgres";

    public Connection connect() {

        Connection conn = null;
        try {
            conn = DriverManager.getConnection(url, user, password);
            System.out.println("[LitopiaServices] Connected to the PostgreSQL");
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        }

        return conn;
    }
}
```

and because I use maven in my pom.xml I have add this :

```xml
<dependency>
            <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
            <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
            <version>42.2.14</version>
</dependency>
```

but when I run my code like that

```java
DBConnection db = new DBConnection();
db.connect();
```

I have the No suitable driver found exception for jdbc:postgresql... But as you see I have install my driver and my connection class as the same code as the doc example. So I really don't understood what going on.

Comment: Are you _sure_ the jar is on the classpath?

Comment: How do you build and then run the code? Adding the dependency will help you compile - but having it in the classpath for running is a different thing

Comment: How I can know if my jar is on the class path ?

Comment: I'm using jar files to test it and same error

Answer (score 5, accepted):

So my problem come from the class name that don't be fined so to solve it I have add before my connection :

```java
Class.forName("org.postgresql.Driver");
conn = DriverManager.getConnection(url, user, password);
```

And it works !